# Android Virtual Device installation on windows failing

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, haxm

I am trying to configure AVD on windows 7 .
While configuring HAXM installer i am getting below error.

I have installed android studio in "c:\android" directory.

```
Looking for SDK updates...
Android SDK is up to date.
Running Intel® HAXM installer
Failed to cleanup temporary folder C:\Users\GaneshPat\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\Program Files\Python\intel\HAXM\6.0.1\silent
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
HAXM installation failed. To install HAXM follow the instructions found at: https://software.intel.com/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windowsDone
```

Comment: Your system PATH variable is misconfigured. `C:\Program Files` is being split at the space, and therefore causing an error

Comment: I think you should reinstall HAXM and not place it inside your Python program files folder.

Comment: 1 ) HAXM installation wizard does not ask the installation path . 2 ) I tried changing the program files key in REGEDIT at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion to point to directory with no spaces. But no help either. Any thing i am missing more ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your user and system 'TEMP' enviroment variable, remove all waste directories, remove ending semicolon if present, and all paths with spaces must be enclosed in quotes.